# Prove that $Ω$ has no accumulation point

Tags: general-topology

Let $f,g,h,l:ℂ→ℝ$ four harmonic functions such that $f≠g$ and $h≠l$.

Let $D$ be an open set in $ℂ$. Let us define the set:

$$Ω:\{ s=α+iβ∈D:f(s)=g(s),h(s)=l(s)\}$$

My question is: Prove that $Ω$ has no accumulation point, i.e., the set $Ω$ is discrete.

Comment: I assume $f\neq g$ and $h\neq l$?

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan: Yes, I add this remark to the question.

Comment: Chaos, to write literal parenthesees type \{ and \} instead of just { and }.

Comment: @Chaos,   Are you sure the condition on the functions is that they're continuous? Is it not that they are holomorphic (or analytic)?

Comment: @DonAntonio: Yes, I add harmonic in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assumptions do **not** imply that $\Omega$ is discrete in $D$. Let's assume for simplicity that $0 \in D$, and write $x = \Re z$ and $y = \Im z$. Then

$$\begin{align}
f(z) &= x,\\
g(z) &= xy,\\
h(z) &= xy^2 - \frac13 x^3,\\
l(z) &= xy^3 - x^3y,
\end{align}$$

are four different harmonic functions, but $D\cap i\mathbb{R} \subset \Omega$, that means $\Omega$ contains a nondegenerate line segment.

To obtain the conclusion that $\Omega$ has no accumulation point in $D$, you need stronger assumptions, for example that $h$ is a harmonic conjugate of $f$ and $l$ a harmonic conjugate of $g$, so that $\Omega$ is the zero set of the holomorphic function $m(z) = (f(z) + ih(z)) - (g(z) + il(z))$ which does not identically vanish by the assumption $f \neq g$.

Answer (score 1):

Hints;

Suppose $\;w\in\Omega\;$ is an accumulation point of $\;\Omega\;$ , so that

$$\exists\;\{w_n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}\subset\Omega\;\;s.t.\;\;w_n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}w$$

If we write $\;w_n=\alpha_n+i\beta_n\;,\;\;\alpha,\beta\in\Bbb R\;$ , we get

$$f(w_n)=g(w_n)\;,\;\;h(w_n)=l(w_n)\;,\;\;\forall\,n\in\Bbb N$$

Now read [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem) , in particular the Improvement.

Comment: But the identity theorem holds true only for analytic functions.

Comment: That's right, @Chaos, yet if your domain $\;D\;$ is not only open but in fact *simply connected* then harmonic real-valued complex functions are the real( imaginary) part of anaytic functions, so you could form the functions $\;f+ih\;,\;\;g+il\;$ . If you don't have simply connected then I'm not sure the above works.

Comment: The domain is $D:{s=α+iβ∈ℂ: a<α<b}$

Comment: What is $\,a,b\;$ here? It must be either given or else possible to prove that $\;D\;$ is simply connected to use what I wrote in my past comment.

Comment: $a$ and $b$ are real numbers

Comment: That I did gather alone, @Chaos : what do they have to do here with your question *at all* ?

Comment: they are given by definition in the topic of this question.

Comment: Where in your question are they given, @Chaos ?

Comment: I did not write them since I think that they are not importnat.

Comment: The functions are harmonic not analytic.

Comment: I know, @Chaos...that's why I wrote about simple connected, because in that case harmonic $\,\implies$ analytic...

Comment: $f + ih$ is in general not analytic (holomorphic) if $f$ and $h$ are arbitrary real-valued harmonic functions. It is holomorphic if and only if $h$ is a harmonic conjugate of $f$. (@Chaos too.)