# Prove that $Ω$ is closed in the standard topology

Tags: general-topology

The motivation to this question can be found in: [Prove that $Ω$ has no accumulation point](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/471885/prove-that-has-no-accumulation-point)

My question is: Prove that $Ω$ is closed in the standard topology.

Comment: What equivalent definitions of "closed" do you have available to you?

Comment: @CameronBuie: In a topological space, a set is closed if and only if it coincides with its closure. Equivalently, a set is closed if and only if it contains all of its limit points

Comment: Good. How do "limit point" and "accumulation point" differ, if at all?

Comment: Generally, these terms refer to the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\Omega$ has no accumulation points (which are the same thing as limit points, in your context), then it vacuously contains all of its limit points (since the set of its limit points is the empty set), and so is closed.